# What's the cost of scan including column that has been added recently?

Tags: google-bigquery

Assuming I have an old table with a lot of data. Two columns are there - `user_id` existing from very beginning and `data` added very recently, say, a week ago. My goal is to join this table on `user_id` but retrieve only the newly created column `data`. Could it be the case that because `data` column didn't exist so far, there is no point of scanning whole `user_id` range and, therefore, query would be cheaper? How is the price calculated for such operation?

Comment: you still will be billed for whole two columns scan

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) there are 2 pricing models for queries:

- [On-demand pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing)
- [Flat-rate pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#flat_rate_pricing)

Seeing that you use On-demand pricing, you will only be billed by the number of bytes processed, you can check how data size is calculated [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data). In that sense the answer would be: yes, scanning `user_id` partially would be cheaper. But reading through the documentation you'll find this sentence:

> When you run a query, you're charged according to the data processed in the columns you select, even if you set an explicit `LIMIT` on the results.

So probably the best solution would be creating another table with the data that has to be processed and run the query.

Comment: If I'd pay flat rate question would have no sense, would it? I am not asking about what types of pricing plans are there but how this concrete situation is going to be priced as it's interesting corner case.